# Multiprocessing inside another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have such looped functions in this form:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def foo_1(i):
    count = 1
    for something:
        # blah blah blah
        h=0
        while len()<count:
          def foo_2(j):
              # blah blah blah
              return i + j
          h = h+1
        count +=1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = Pool(4)
    pool.imap_unordered(foo_2, range()):

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

How should the syntax look like to make it work? Because giving `if __name__ == '__main __'` inside `foo_1` does not work, and if I put it at the end, it does not recognize the function`foo_2`. Or maybe you need to completely rebuild the code syntax?

Comment: The problem is that `foo_2` is a completely different function on each iteration. And, even if you never call `foo_1`, you won't be able to access it, as it's defined on "runtime", in the same way you'd not be able to access any other private variable.

Answer (score 2):

I would change the structure of the code.  Below is what I would do.  Just curious, why do you want to use multi-processing on foo_2 vice foo_1?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# method broken out
def foo_2(j, i):
    # blah blah blah
    return i + j

def foo_1(i):
    count = 1
    for something:
        # blah blah blah
        h=0
        while len()<count:
          return_foo_2 = foo_2(j, i)
          h = h+1
        count +=1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = Pool(4)

    # you will have to create a list of tasks to run
    # in your multiprocessing pool
    list_tasks = [(range(), range())]
    pool.imap_unordered(foo_2, list_tasks):

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```